# Missing function argument error

Tags: php, function, post

I want to use a function to echo a value I named, "name". The value is sent to the function via the POST method from a form.

My HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> function play </title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="function.php">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My PHP:

```
<?php
$name= $_POST['name'];
function writeName($name)
{
echo $name;
}
writeName();
?>
```

For some reason I keep getting the error:

Warning: Missing argument 1 for writeName(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\function.php on line 7 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\function.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined variable: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\function.php on line 5

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a parameter in to the function.

```
writeName($name);
```

Comment: Or in the OP's case, `writeName($name);`

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you need to pass your value as as an argument when you call the function.

Variables in PHP are ["scoped"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).  This means that wherever you define your variable will affect its context.  In your example, $name defined at the script level is not the same as $name defined as a function parameter.  However, $name used within your function will always refer to the same variable *within that function*.

[image]

To put that in practice, consider the following:

```
$name = 'a';
function writeName( $name )
{
    echo $name; // echoes 'b'
}
writeName( 'b' );
echo $name;  //echoes 'a'
```

Another way to think about it is by just changing the names of the variables so they are noticeably different:

```
$getName= $_POST[ 'name' ];

function writeName( $nameToWrite )
{
    echo $nameToWrite;
}

writeName( $getName );
```

You can also use the `global` keyword inside your function to let PHP know that you're referencing a variable in the global scope (i.e., at the script level, outside your function) but this is generally bad practice.

```
$getName = $_POST[ 'name' ];

function writeName()   // Notice that we don't need to pass $getName as an argument
{
    global $getName;
    echo $getName;
}

writeName();
```

Answer (score 1):

You defined your function as `function writeName($name)`, which means it's expecting an argument. But when you call the function, you don't pass an argument. Try changing

```
writeName();
```

to:

```
writeName($name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a parameter to the function `writeName($name);`

**or** you can set a default for the function parameter:

```
function writeName($name = null)
{
   echo $name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing the parameter to the function. Try this:

```
<?php
function writeName($name)
{
echo $name;
}
writeName($_POST['name']);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is: you declared your `writeName` function as expecting an argument called `$name`. But when you call the function, you are not passing any parameters. You should use the function like this:

```
writeName("some string here");
```

Answer (score 0):

You've defined your 'writeName' function to accept one parameter. When calling the function you must provide this parameter.

```
writeName($name);
```

or

```
writeName($_POST['name']);
```